# Rails 5, pry seems to break app despite rb-readline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I was experimenting with adding facebook oauth to an app and needed to use pry to investigate a problem. However, whenever rails hits the pry, it breaks the app and throws an error. I’ve tried a bunch of proposed solutions (I added rb-readline, pry-nav, pry-coolline, and brew link readline —force). I'm not sure what exactly is wrong.

Here's the error in the browser

```
LoadError in SessionsController#create
dlopen(/Users/noah/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib Referenced from: /Users/noah/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle Reason: image not found - /Users/noah/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
```

## gemfile.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'listen'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'rb-readline'
# gem 'pry-nav' # this proposed solution failed
# gem 'pry-coolline' # this proposed solution failed
group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7.0'
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 1.10.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'valid_attribute'
end
```

## models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # binding.pry # why in the fuck doesn't pry work?!
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.first_name = auth.extra.raw_info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.extra.raw_info.last_name
      user.oath_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oath_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

## controller/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Feeling pretty clueless. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I believe that is all the relevant code unless you also want to see what I have done for the facebook oauth

Comment: Looking at your Gemfile that you posted it looks like you don't have it installed.

Comment: I forgot to post the development section of the gemfile. It's included there
`group :development, :test do`
  `gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7.0'`
  `gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 1.10.1'`
  `gem 'factory_girl_rails'`
  `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'`
  `gem 'pry-rails'`
  `gem 'shoulda'`
  `gem 'valid_attribute'`
`end`

Comment: Post your SessionsController code. The error you are getting seems to have nothing to do with pry and the error is in your SessionsController not your User model code.

Comment: class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

Comment: I have a feeling that if you remove `rb-readline` from your Gemfile it might work.